# Probability - Show inequality $P(A \cap B) \ge P(A) + P(B)-1$

Tags: probability, inequality, inclusion-exclusion

My task is to show that:
$$P(A \cap B) \ge P(A) + P(B)-1$$
The rule inclusion-exclusion is:
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
If I rewrite this rule, I get
$$P(A\cap B) = -P(A \cup B) + P(A) + P(B)$$
Am I on the right track, and if so, how do I proceed?

Comment: $0\le P(A\cup B)\le1$ and $-1\le -P(A\cup B)\le0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track. Now, you should that any probability is $\le 1$.
So $P(A\cup B)\le 1\implies -P(A\cup B)\ge -1$. 
Hence your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are completely on the right track. Now, if you get easily confused by the direction of inequalities you could also write
$$
P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)
$$
since in $(\Omega,P,\mathcal{F})$ we have
$$
\forall A\in\mathcal{F}: 1\geq P(A)
$$
as
$$
1\geq P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)
$$
so 
$$
1\geq P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)\Leftrightarrow P(A \cap B)\geq P(A) + P(B)-1
$$